# Consulta LINQ con Objeto que contiene List<int>

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

tengo que hacer una consulta Linq usando un Objeto Pasajero que contiene una lista de dni:

```
public class Pasajero
    {
        public List<string> nombre { get; set;}
        public List<string> apellido { get; set; }
        public List<int> edad { get; set; }
        public List<int> dni { get; set; }
        public List<string> nacionalidad { get; set; }
        public List<string> fechaNacimiento { get; set; }
        public string sexo { get; set; }

    }
```

Mi metodo recibe un pasajero que puede contener muchos dnis, que son los que se insertan en un formulario.

```
 public List<Cliente> buscarCliente(Pasajero pasajero)
        {


            List<Cliente> Totalclientes = (from c in ctx.Cliente where c.Documento = pasajero.dni select c).ToList();

            return Totalclientes;

        }}
```

el error me lo da en la parte de "pasajero.dni"

> no se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo
>   'system.collections.generic.list  en int?

la idea es buscar todos los clientes con esos dnis que se ingresan en un Formulario.

Gracias por su aporte!!

Comment: Hay inconsecuencia en lo que quieres hacer y en lo que necesitas, porque dices querer **obtener todos los clientes o pasajeros que estan en una lista de dnis**, pero en el codigo que estas tratando de obtener un listado de clientes. El error lo lanza porque Documento debe ser un int y pasajero.dni es una lista de enteros.

Comment: Si, Documente es un int y pasajero.dni es una lista. Lo que quiero obtener es una lista de Clientes. Ahora mi duda es como hacer que busque todos los clientes dentro de una lista de dnis, Me explico?

Comment: @AlanSnyder: Indica por favor tu clase (Modelo) **Cliente**

Comment: En ese caso lo que debes hacer es tomar la lista de DNIS que tienes, recorrerla con un loop y por cada cliente encontrado, agregarlo en una lista con el metodo Add

Comment: Perfecto, voy a intentar eso. El problema es que del form viaja directo como una lista dentro de una clase (la clase Pasajero que contiene esa lista de dnis), porque desconozco la forma de enviar una lista de dnis en un form, ya que este puede variar en cuanto a cantidad de inputs.

Comment: Facil, recorres en el loop de esta forma `foreach(int d in pasajero.dni) { // codigo... }`. Aun asi, considera el comentario que te hice, **no tiene logica que una persona tengo N dnis**. Nos cuentas como te va!

Comment: No tiene logica, pero como hago entonces para mandar una lista de DNI en un formulario?

Comment: No deberias... analiza porque estas enviando una lista de dnis asignados a una persona, cuando solo deberia ser una propiedad. Porque envias esa lista?

Comment: Es una pagina de venta de pasajes, a la hora de cargar los datos de los clientes necesito revisar si el o los clientes existen, por eso en un form (Que se recorre con un foreach ya que varia la cantidad de pasajeros) envio uno o varios dnis y luego valido que existan.

Comment: Entiendo.. perfecto! Lo que pasa ahi es que esa lista de DNIS esta bien.. lo que esta mal, es que este asignada a pasajeros, deberia ser una relacion de 1 a 1, no de 1 a N. Bastaria con crear una clase auxiliar, un viewModel, etc que reciba un listado de dnis solamente, nada mas

Comment: Buenos es que ahí recide uno de mis problemas, puedo mandar una lista de Dnis en un Form (Que reciba por ejemplo List<int>Dnis)?

Comment: Perfectamente! Solo deberias construir un form en el que solo se puedan registrar dnis y listo! No tiene mas complejidad que eso

Answer (score 0):

Este es tu problema:

> "pasajero.dni.Contains(c.Documento)" ERROR: Argumento 1: no se puede
>   convertir de 'int?' a 'int'

Seguramente en tu Clase `Cliente`, la propiedad `Documento` es de tipo **int?** (nullable), por eso te he dicho que indiques la clase `Cliente`. Haz un **cast** a **Int32**.

Prueba a realizar tu consulta LinQ de esta manera:

```
List<Cliente> Totalclientes = (from c in ctx.Cliente where pasajero.dni.Contains((Int32)c.Documento) select c).ToList();
```

Comment: Si eso esta así por una razón, pero lo que necesito saber es como generar una consulta Linq con una lista de dni

Comment: Un pasajero puede tener muchos DNIs?.

Comment: No necesariamente, pero uso esa clase para guardar dnis que viajan por un formulario en el que pueden variar la cantidad de dnis que se manden

Comment: @AlanSnyder un DNI es un valor unico asignado a una persona unica, no puede ser que una persona, pasajero y/o cliente tenga asignados N dnis. Considera modificar la estructura de tus datos en este caso, porque de lo contrario podrias tener problemas futuros

Answer (score 0):

el error que tienes es que estas comparando tipos differentes (int contra List).

Tal vez esto es lo que buscas.

```
List<Cliente> Totalclientes = (from c in ctx.Cliente where  pasajero.dni.Contains(c.Documento) select c).ToList();
```

Comment: "pasajero.dni.Contains(c.Documento)" ERROR: Argumento 1: no se puede convertir de 'int?' a 'int'

Answer (score 0):

Primero que nada creo que la clase pasajero debería estar definida de la siguiente manera:

```
public class Pasajero
{
    public string nombre { get; set;}
    public string apellido { get; set; }
    public int edad { get; set; }
    public List<int> dni { get; set; }
    public string nacionalidad { get; set; }
    public string fechaNacimiento { get; set; }
    public string sexo { get; set; }

}
```

Y el metodo:

```
public List<Cliente> buscarCliente(Pasajero pasajero)
    {


        List<Cliente> Totalclientes = (from c in ctx.Cliente where pasajero.dni.Contains((int)c.Documento) select c).ToList();

        return Totalclientes;

    }}
```